# Using "yo jhipster" when offline

Tags: jhipster

I was wondering if there is a way to generate a JHipster project when offline.
I see that Yeoman downloads lots of stuff, even if I generate 10 times the same project.

Answer (score 0):

You can stop the process when yeoman starts `npm install & bower install` when generating project with `yo jhipster`. Then You can copy `node_modules` and `bower_components` from already generated project inside newly generated Jhipster project.